# Dynamically build 2D array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic

I want to build a 2 dimensional array dynamically, but I'm having trouble.

answers and votes (single string arrays) will always be the same length;

**I need an array like this:**

```
var data = 
        [['Answer', 'Votes'],
        [answers[0],  parseInt(votes[0])],
        [answers[1],  parseInt(votes[1])],
        [answers[2],  parseInt(votes[2])],
          ....
        ];
```

**This doesn't work;**

```
var data[];
var arrayLength = answers.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    data += [answers[i], votes[i]]; //**Maybe the only line that needs tweaking?
}
```

Comment: does answers array has the same length with the votes array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = [];

data[0] = ['answers','votes']

var arrayLength = answers.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    data[i+1]= [answers[i], parseInt(votes[i])]; 
}

//check
console.table(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = [];
var arrayLength = answers.length;
data[0] = ['Answer', 'Votes'];
for (var i = 1; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    data.push([answers[i], votes[i]]); /*It's not += but .push()*/
}
```

Comment: Ah yeah. I've missed it. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: he copied off my bad declaration ;) .. Thanks @Xlander

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = [];
var arrayLength = answers.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    data.push([answers[i], votes[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote `answers [i]` and  `votes[i]` so, it seems your answers and votes are in two different array. so why the loop is needed.

**Suppose answers and votes are:**

```
var answers = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
var votes = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
```

**building new array**

```
var data = ["Answers", "Votes"];

data.Answers=answers;
data.Votes=votes;

console.log(data);
```